# Newrelic isn't recognizing my Slim PHP routes

Tags: php, url-rewriting, frameworks, slim, newrelic

I have just set up New Relic on my PHP web app. Everything is working great except one thing... All of the transactions show as going through "index.php".

The reason for this because I'm using the [Slim framework](http://slimframework.com/) (there [are](https://github.com/nramenta/bento) [many](https://github.com/anandkunal/ToroPHP) [alternatives](https://github.com/ChiperSoft/Karte) [for](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/) [routing](http://phalconphp.com/)) with URL rewriting so that I can have nice human URLs like "/user/settings" without a folder for every controller and action.

But that still leaves me with `index.php` as the name for every New Relic web transaction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use a hook to set the transaction name to the name or pattern of the router.

Here is an example setting it to the pattern:

```
$app->hook('slim.before.dispatch', function() use ($app) {
    newrelic_name_transaction($app->router()->getCurrentRoute()->getPattern());
});
```

Answer (score 8):

It took me some searching, however I was able to find an answer ([available here](http://dev.bluszcz.net/blog/new-relic-and-php-codeigniter-controller-action-integration)) related to CodeIgniter.

A little modification made it work for me (with Slim), and I imagine other PHP routers and frameworks will have roughly the same solution:

```
if (extension_loaded ('newrelic')) {
    newrelic_name_transaction($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
}
```

Edit: to avoid including any GET parameters, use this on the second line:

```
newrelic_name_transaction(current(explode('?', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])))
```

*Note: Emerson's answer, where he recommends using the route pattern, is a much better option than using the literal URL if you are using Slim.*

Comment: You might want to have a look at this: "You should absolutely *NOT* include any request-specific data in the transaction name. So for example, using the actual request URL is extremely bad." https://newrelic.com/docs/php/framework-developers-integrated-support-for-new-relic

Comment: They say that - but they dont really offer an allternative

Comment: I think in many cases the request url isn't going to be useful to people. For example, if you have an e-commerce site with 10,000 products, you'd want 'product page' as a single action and not 10,000 individual ones. Otherwise it'd be hard to get much out of the reporting UI.

Answer (score 1):

New Relic now has out-of-the-box support for the Slim Framework starting with version [6.7.0.174](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/release-notes/agent-release-notes/php-release-notes/php-agent-670174) of the PHP Agent.

Answer (score 0):

I updated to the NewRelic agent 6.9.0.182 but transactions are still not named so I put a middleware (since Slim 3 does not support hook anymore) instead and it works better:

```
$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => [
    // to be able access to route within middleware
    'determineRouteBeforeAppMiddleware' => true,
]]);

// middleware to send the correct route to NewRelic
$app->add(function ($request, $response, $next) {
    if (extension_loaded('newrelic') && $request->getAttribute('route')) {
        newrelic_name_transaction($request->getAttribute('route')->getPattern());
    }

    return $next($request, $response);
});

// loads some routes

$app->run();
```